# Image isn't displayed while iterating through while-loop

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

Actually I'm coding a little flood "simulator". So one method is to read a time-series of flooding levels from a file and show them for a couple seconds in my window. The awkward this is that only the last flood-event is displayed but all lines are read correctly from the file (I double checked this).

```
private void timeFlood(File file)
{
    System.out.println("timeFlood()");
    String path = file.getParent();
    String name = file.getName();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String date;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((date = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(date != null) {
                img = model.getFloodedImageWithHeight(Float.parseFloat(date.split(",")[0]),
                        Float.parseFloat(uncertainty.getText()), floodfill.isSelected());
                String percent = String.format("%.2f", model.getPercentFloodedArea() * 100.0f);
                percent = percent.split(",")[0] + "." + percent.split(",")[1] + "%";
                flooded_area.setText("Flooded Area: " + percent);
                level.setText("Waterlevel: " + date.split(",")[0] + " Meters");
                icon.setImage(img);
                image.setIcon(icon);
                image.repaint();
                parseTerLegend();*/
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Might be the problem that the while-loop iterates to fast? So the JLable image can't update itself fast enough?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Ok. I deleted that call. But there isn't any of the generetad images displayed, except from the very last one

Comment: @fightingpilot Read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to better understand the issue and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution